# How to activate and deactivate frame in java?

Tags: java, jframe

I had made one application in java-swing,
Now what i am getting problem is,
i want to minimize my jframe  when it is deactivate and then to maximize i want to activate that window.

So for maximize, i want to activate any jframe using java code.
So how to activate and deactivate any jframe, so that i can do something on window listeners?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean be deactivate/activate? Has lost focus/gained focus?

Comment: Having read your question again now, I'm not quite sure I totally understand what it is you're trying to do. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: here i want to gain focus on any frame, so as soon as i get focus then that frame will be in active mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
import java.awt.Frame;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        // Create a test frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello");
        frame.add(new JLabel("Minimize demo"));
        frame.pack();

        // Show the frame
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Sleep for 5 seconds, then minimize
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        frame.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED);

        // Sleep for 5 seconds, then restore
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        frame.setState(Frame.NORMAL);

        // Sleep for 5 seconds, then kill window
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.dispose();

        // Terminate test
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Modified from http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/faq/faq0055.html

---

To focus the window you can do `frame.requestFocus();`.

Comment: i know how can i minimize and maximize the jframe but i want to know,
how set any frame to activate mode and deactivate mode.?

Comment: What is activate / deactivate mode?!

Comment: sorry guys,i was writing that code on some other function.
so thank u 4 replay.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to add a WindowListener to your JFrame, and add the following logic to your listener:

```
public class Demo extends JFrame implements WindowListener {

    public Demo() {
        addWindowListener(this);
    }

    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
        setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | Frame.ICONIFIED);
    }

    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
        setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my practice, I often encountered a problem when the window is not activated when the usual attributes are set:
frame.setVisible (true);
frame.setState (Frame.NORMAL);

and I found a solution where the window is activated:

```
frame.setExtendedState (JFrame.ICONIFIED);
frame.setExtendedState (JFrame.NORMAL);
frame.toFront ();
frame.requestFocus ();

// frame - JFrame
```